# Using VBA to unlock a cell if another cells returns an error

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, I & Q, both with formulas in them.  If the formula in Q returns an error, I want to unlock the cell in column I of that row. Here's what I have and it doesn't work:

```
Private Sub UnlockError(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
          
    If Intersect(Target, Sheet2.Range("Q:Q")) Is Nothing Then GoTo ResetEvents
    
    If IsError(Target) Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="@Pentagon2020"
    Target.Offset(0, -8).Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="@Pentagon2020"
    End If
    
ResetEvents:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: you cannot just create a new event.  The code would need to be called from an existing event like Worksheet_Change and the reference passed in.

Comment: and a formula returning an error would not trip the Worksheet_change so you would either need to target the cells that feed the data to the formula that causes the error or use a worksheet_calculate event, which does not have `ByVal Target As Range` and cannot be added.

Answer (score 0):

The error that triggers the unlocking of another cell must be within a procedure, as demonstrated in the Change event procedure below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MyError     As Double
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        MyError = 100 / 0
        If Err.Number = 11 Then
            With Cells(Target.Row, "B")
                .Locked = False
                .Select
            End With
        ElseIf Err.Number Then
            MsgBox "An unidentified error occurred.", _
                   vbInformation, "Error messsage"
        Else
            ' continue with your program
            Target.Value = MyError
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want your procedure to look at a cell and determine if it contains an error this code will do it.

```
If IsError(Cells(2, "A") Then
    With Cells(2, "B")
        .Locked = False
        .Select
    End With
End If
```

The problem with this code is that you would either need a button to call it or embed it in another procedure that is called by pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

### Worksheet_Calculate

- The following is a rather un-efficient solution. It will be triggered each time the worksheet gets calculated i.e. a change will happen 'due to' a formula. It will first lock all cells in the `Lock Range` and then unlock the desired ones. If you don't have thousands of rows, this may serve you well.
- A better solution may be to to write all the values in the `Source Range` to a *public* array to keep track of the changes. Then each time the worksheet is calculated, the values of a new array would be checked against the values in the public array. Appropriate changes would be made, and in the end the new array would be written to the public array. Keep in mind that the first writing of the public array could be done by using the `Workbook_Open` event and that rows may get added or deleted.
- The best solution, if possible,  would be to steer this whole operation towards the `Worksheet_Change` event i.e. trace back the formulas to the cells that are changed manually or via `VBA` and are 'causing' the resulting error values. Then checking only the values that got changed would increase efficiency. Keep in mind that in this event `Application.EnableEvents` is often necessary and should be 'accompanied' by error handling.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub unlockErrorValuesInit( _
        ws As Worksheet)
    
    Const sFirst As String = "Q2"
    Const lFirst As String = "I2"
    Const MyPassWord As String = "" '"@Pentagon2020"
    
    unlockErrorValues ws.Range(sFirst), ws.Range(lFirst), MyPassWord
 
End Sub

Sub unlockErrorValues( _
        srcFirstCell As Range, _
        lockFirstCell As Range, _
        Optional ByVal MyPassWord As String = "")

    ' Validate inputs.
    If srcFirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If lockFirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Calculate offsets.
    Dim rOffs As Long: rOffs = lockFirstCell.Row - srcFirstCell.Row
    Dim cOffs As Long: cOffs = lockFirstCell.Column - srcFirstCell.Column
    
    ' Define Source (Column) Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With srcFirstCell
        Set srg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(srg.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    srg.Worksheet.Unprotect MyPassWord
    
    ' Reset Lock (Column) Range (lock all cells).
    With srg.Offset(rOffs, cOffs)
        .Locked = True
        .Interior.Color = xlNone ' to better visualize
    End With

    ' Define Destination Range of Source Range (cells containing error values).
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Unlock cells in Destination Range of Lock Range.
    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        With drg.Offset(rOffs, cOffs)
            .Locked = False
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow ' to better visualize
        End With
    End If
    
    srg.Worksheet.Protect MyPassWord
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`** (the name in parentheses in the `VBE Project Explorer`)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    unlockErrorValuesInit Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay let me tinker with this and wrap my head around it.  The cells that would result in an error are calculated by "index/match", and the error results when there is no match.